# rails 4 to convert text to array helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following string

```
78,87,test,test1,125
```

How can i convert this into an array

I need something like this

```
[78, 87, "test", "test1", 125]
```

How do i achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have an easier time with ruby if you familiarize yourself with the commonly-used classes, like String: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html.

What you want here is:

```
"something,something,something".split ','
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer just for completeness although @struthersneil's answer answers most of it.

```
"78,87,test,test1,125".split(',').map { |x| x=~ /^\d+$/ ? x.to_i : x }
> [78, 87, "test", "test1", 125]
```

Note the use of `map` and `regex` check for numbers.  You should be able to change the regex and appropriate helpers e.g. `to_i`, `to_f` etc. according to your need.